# How can I set mouse cursor properly during drag and drop of TitledPane btw two Accordion in Javafx

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, javafx-8

In the following code example, drag and drop of TitledPanes between two Accordion panes is handled.
The drag and drop works ok, but the problem is setting the mouse pointer correctly.
When doing the drag, the cursor gets set correctly.
And after the drag is complete, the cursor is set to default in most parts.
The exceptions is on the title of the TitledPane, where the MOVE cursor is still set.
The DragDetected event seems to be in some inner class of the TitledPane, see printout of event further down.
Shouldn't this work or what am I doing wrong here?

```
package javafxapplication4;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseDragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Daniel
 */
public class JavaFXApplication4 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        VBox vb1 = new VBox();
        VBox vb2 = new VBox();
        vb1.setPrefHeight(200);
        vb2.setPrefHeight(200);
        Label l1 = new Label("L1");
        Label l2 = new Label("L2");
        Accordion ac1 = new Accordion();
        ac1.setPrefSize(100, 200);
        Accordion ac2 = new Accordion();
        ac2.setPrefSize(100, 200);
        TextArea ta1 = new TextArea();
        TitledPane tp1 = new TitledPane("TP1", ta1);
        ac1.getPanes().add(tp1);
        TextArea ta2 = new TextArea();
        TitledPane tp2 = new TitledPane("TP2", ta2);
        ac2.getPanes().add(tp2);
        vb1.getChildren().add(l1);
        vb2.getChildren().add(l2);
        vb1.getChildren().add(ac1);
        vb2.getChildren().add(ac2);
        hb.getChildren().add(vb1);
        hb.getChildren().add(vb2);

        ac1.setOnMouseDragEntered(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("dragEntered " + event.toString());
                Consumer<Node> se = s -> s.setMouseTransparent(true);
                ac1.getPanes().forEach(se);
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        ac1.setOnMouseDragExited(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("dragExited " + event.toString());
                Consumer<Node> se = s -> s.setMouseTransparent(false);
                ac1.getPanes().forEach(se);
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        ac1.setOnMouseDragReleased(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("dragReleased " + event.toString());
                TitledPane node = (TitledPane) event.getGestureSource();
                Accordion parent = (Accordion) node.getParent();
                parent.getPanes().remove(node);
                Accordion newParent = (Accordion) event.getTarget();
                newParent.getPanes().add(node);
                ((Node) event.getGestureSource()).setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);

                event.consume();
            }
        });
        ac2.setOnMouseDragEntered(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("dragEntered " + event.toString());
                Consumer<Node> se = s -> s.setMouseTransparent(true);
                ac2.getPanes().forEach(se);
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        ac2.setOnMouseDragExited(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("dragExited " + event.toString());
                Consumer<Node> se = s -> s.setMouseTransparent(false);
                ac2.getPanes().forEach(se);
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        ac2.setOnMouseDragReleased(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("dragReleased " + event.toString());
                TitledPane node = (TitledPane) event.getGestureSource();
                Accordion parent = (Accordion) node.getParent();
                parent.getPanes().remove(node);
                Accordion newParent = (Accordion) event.getTarget();
                newParent.getPanes().add(node);
                ((Node) event.getGestureSource()).setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);

                event.consume();
            }
        });

        tp1.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("handle dragDetected " + event);
                tp1.startFullDrag();
                ((Node) event.getTarget()).setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                //tp1.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE); // Doesn't work - default cursor
                event.consume();
            }

        });
        tp1.setOnMouseDragReleased(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("TitledPane mouseDragReleased " + event);
                TitledPane node = (TitledPane) event.getGestureSource();
                Accordion parent = (Accordion) node.getParent();
                parent.getPanes().remove(node);
                Accordion newParent = (Accordion) ((TitledPane) event.getSource()).getParent();
                newParent.getPanes().add(node);
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        tp2.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println("handle dragDetected " + event);
                ((Node) event.getTarget()).setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
                //tp2.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);// Doesn't work - default cursor
                tp2.startFullDrag();
                event.consume();
            }

        });
        tp2.setOnMouseDragReleased(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                System.out.println("TitledPane mouseDragReleased " + event);
                TitledPane node = (TitledPane) event.getGestureSource();
                Accordion parent = (Accordion) node.getParent();
                parent.getPanes().remove(node);
                Accordion newParent = (Accordion) ((TitledPane) event.getSource()).getParent();
                newParent.getPanes().add(node);
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(hb);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Drag drop mouse cursor example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

It produces this output for a drag n drop:

```
handle dragDetected MouseEvent [source = TitledPane@44ce2e46[styleClass=titled-pane first-titled-pane]'TP1', target = TitledPaneSkin$TitleRegion@451c360f[styleClass=title], eventType = DRAG_DETECTED, consumed = false, x = 71.0, y = 4.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, primaryButtonDown, pickResult = PickResult [node = TitledPaneSkin$TitleRegion@451c360f[styleClass=title], point = Point3D [x = 71.0, y = 4.0, z = 0.0], distance = 466.5063509461097]
dragEntered MouseDragEvent [source = Accordion@19ef71a8[styleClass=accordion], target = Accordion@19ef71a8[styleClass=accordion], gestureSource = TitledPane@44ce2e46[styleClass=titled-pane first-titled-pane]'TP1', eventType = MOUSE-DRAG_ENTERED, consumed = false, x = 71.0, y = 4.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, primaryButtonDown, pickResult = PickResult [node = TitledPaneSkin$TitleRegion@451c360f[styleClass=title], point = Point3D [x = 71.0, y = 4.0, z = 0.0], distance = 466.5063509461097]
dragExited MouseDragEvent [source = Accordion@19ef71a8[styleClass=accordion], target = Accordion@19ef71a8[styleClass=accordion], gestureSource = TitledPane@44ce2e46[styleClass=titled-pane first-titled-pane]'TP1', eventType = MOUSE-DRAG_EXITED, consumed = false, x = 108.0, y = 3.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, primaryButtonDown, pickResult = PickResult [node = TitledPaneSkin$TitleRegion@1f91afb1[styleClass=title], point = Point3D [x = 8.0, y = 3.0, z = 0.0], distance = 466.5063509461097]
dragEntered MouseDragEvent [source = Accordion@77b6ca53[styleClass=accordion], target = Accordion@77b6ca53[styleClass=accordion], gestureSource = TitledPane@44ce2e46[styleClass=titled-pane first-titled-pane]'TP1', eventType = MOUSE-DRAG_ENTERED, consumed = false, x = 8.0, y = 3.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, primaryButtonDown, pickResult = PickResult [node = TitledPaneSkin$TitleRegion@1f91afb1[styleClass=title], point = Point3D [x = 8.0, y = 3.0, z = 0.0], distance = 466.5063509461097]
dragReleased MouseDragEvent [source = Accordion@77b6ca53[styleClass=accordion], target = Accordion@77b6ca53[styleClass=accordion], gestureSource = TitledPane@44ce2e46[styleClass=titled-pane first-titled-pane]'TP1', eventType = MOUSE-DRAG_RELEASED, consumed = false, x = 70.0, y = 64.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, pickResult = PickResult [node = Accordion@77b6ca53[styleClass=accordion], point = Point3D [x = 70.0, y = 64.0, z = 0.0], distance = 466.5063509461097]
dragExited MouseDragEvent [source = Accordion@77b6ca53[styleClass=accordion], target = Accordion@77b6ca53[styleClass=accordion], gestureSource = TitledPane@44ce2e46[styleClass=titled-pane]'TP1', eventType = MOUSE-DRAG_EXITED, consumed = false, x = 70.0, y = 64.0, z = 0.0, button = PRIMARY, pickResult = PickResult [node = Accordion@77b6ca53[styleClass=accordion], point = Point3D [x = 70.0, y = 64.0, z = 0.0], distance = 466.5063509461097]
```

THe strange part is *target = TitledPaneSkin$TitleRegion@451c360f[styleClass=title]*
I would have expected TitledPane there.
I think this is the reason why the mouse cursor is not reset properly.

Comment: I can see the MOVE cursor even when I hover over either of the TitledPane. Is it expected?

Comment: No, that is not what I expected

Comment: I found an ugly way to solve this. By adding this to both dragReleasedHandlers:

     `Consumer<Node> g = t -> t.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

     ((TitledPane) event.getGestureSource()).getChildrenUnmodifiable().forEach(g);`

But it seems to be a quite ugly solution, so I assume there is a more correct way of doing this.